# Creating 'taggable' relationships

Tags: foreign-keys, rdbms

Say I have two tables that can have 'tags' associated with them. With potentially more in the future.

**tracks** - 
`id`, `title`, `artist`, `etc...`

**artists** - 
`id`, `name`, `description`, `etc...`

I want to be able to have a general table called 'tags'

**tags** - 
`id`, `title`, `description`

How would I construct the joining table to create the relationship? Is it possible to have it such that foreign keys are applicable to both `artists` and `tracks` table?

I was thinking of a structure similar to:

**tag_relations** - 
`tag_id` (foreign key to `tags.id`), `item_id` (either `artists.id` or `tracks.id`)

Is this a bad design not having any foreign key integrity on the `item_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supports polymorphic relationships which I believe suit the purpose that I require. You can read up about them here.

http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations